# How to re-allocate (or increase) memory to Ubuntu 18 running as a dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 18.04, boot-partition

I've installed ubuntu 18,04 to my laptop, and it's been running as a dual boot.

The problem is that I only allocated less than 7 GB of memory, which made this Ubuntu very slow.
[image]

As you can see, the disk of this laptop has more than 600GB.
Is it possible to allocate more memory now?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: You may buy new memory stick, this is nothing related to allocated memory. I'm afraid that adding more swap (configured during installating) will not improve performances. But 6.8Gbit should be enough. Consider moving to an SSD drive if hard drive performances are too low.

Comment: Memory = Ram != Disk. In a dual boot setup ubuntu should use all available ram.

Comment: Your motherboard is sharing system memory to your video card so this is causing your decrease that you are seeing.  You might just have too much running on your system that is taking up your RAM causing your slow down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned the dual-boot configuration will have nothing to do with memory usage. I'm guessing you have 8gigs of RAM installed which is plenty for most users, unless you run memory intensive apps. If you find the system is swapping a lot, then upgrade your RAM to 16gigs. The operating system (Ubuntu or Windows) can only access 6.8gigs because the rest is taken by the system for shared memory, hardware operation, and built-in graphics. My system has 32gigs but only 31.1 is usable as the other 900megs is used by the hardware in the system. This is normal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting confused between the terms memory and disk.Memory means the capacity of ram which is a seperate module from disk.Rams are generally very fast in comparison to disk(which is why we need them).Size of memory can only be increased by adding more rams into your ram-slots.You cannot use disk as memory.

Coming to dual boot systems,only one os will use resources at a time.You cannot share resources like ram since complete ram is utilised every time you reboot.Since disks are persistent across reboots,you have to share them.So in short,you can share disk but not memory.